# How to replicate SQL Server 7

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, replication

So I want to develop a replication an SQL Server 7.0 database on a remote Windows Server 2000 Advanced to an SQL Server 2008 R2 database on a local Windows 7 machine, using Visual Studio 2012, as I looked for ways to do so, I found that there are certain assemblies I should add to my project which are located in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server** , the folders I found in that location were: 80, 90, 100, 110, 120 and 130 which indicated the assemblies of a certain SQL Server edition each, the thing is, *there is no folder named 70*, meaning there are no assemblies linked to SQL Server 7.0, does that mean Visual Studio 2012 doesn't work with SQL Server 7.0 and earlier editions? and if it does work, can someone point me to where I could find the assemblies or download them?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to import the old database on a new server and move from there?

Comment: Even SQL Server 2005 is out of support now because of its age, why do you still have SQL Server 7?

Comment: I asked my administrator/boss the same question, he said we have our reasons to keep the legacy database and that my job is to find a way to replicate in an SQL Server 2000 R2

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177398(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @MohamedaliHamdi do those reasons include the impossibility of working with incompatible versions 20 years later? I suggest you find a new company. Given the capabilities of SQL Server 7, you could migrate to the free SQL Server 2016 **Express** and get 100x better performance

Comment: I am only an intern, and my internship objectif is accomplishing this task, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the built-in replication features, since [replication with SQL Server 2008 R2 requires SQL Server 2000 SP3 or higher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241(v=sql.105).aspx).

Thus, you'd have to develop your own replication from scratch. Since this will be a time- and cost-intensive endeavor, you will first need to specify *which* replication features you actually need. Then plan for a lot of time and budget (many times the budget that migrating to a new SQL Server would cost).

Comment: Given the 20 year difference, one should consider that SQL Server 2016 Express can handle the same load for free, with orders of magnitude better performance. On a laptop (free backup power!)

Comment: It is not up to me to do that, I am ordered to replicate it

Comment: I don't know why I got downvoted

Comment: I didn't know asking for advice could get you downvoted, nice community